# How to align visibility in pgf-umlcd?

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgf-umlcd

[image]

code here-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{class}[text width = 8cm]{JavaLanguageBehavior}{0,0}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \attribute{- uniqueInstance : JavaLanguageBehavior}
    \operation{+ getUniqueInstance : JavaLanguageBehavior}
    \operation{+ runCode(file : File) : BufferedReader}
    \operation{+ buildCode(file : File) : BufferedReader}
    \operation{+ setHighlightableText()}
    \operation{+ setAutoCompletableText()}
  \end{class}
  \node [above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {Singleton Pattern};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I use a `-`(private) as visibility the `uniqueInstance` variable goes to left. How can I align the visibility and variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want to use `$-$`, so that it becomes a minus sign instead of a hyphen, which in turn means that the widths are similar.

For consistency, set the plus signs in math mode as well.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{class}[text width = 8cm]{JavaLanguageBehavior}{0,0}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \attribute{$-$ uniqueInstance : JavaLanguageBehavior}
    \operation{$+$ getUniqueInstance : JavaLanguageBehavior}
    \operation{$+$ runCode(file : File) : BufferedReader}
    \operation{$+$ buildCode(file : File) : BufferedReader}
    \operation{$+$ setHighlightableText()}
    \operation{$+$ setAutoCompletableText()}
  \end{class}
  \node [above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {Singleton Pattern};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guessed that you will answer. But should I need `$+$` for `+` instead of only `+`?

Comment: @alhelal Didn't seem to make a difference in this case, I did it just for consistency. But it will depend on font setup, if you're using a math font with smaller plus/minus signs you could see a small difference.

Comment: Yes. Consistency is important. I recommend you to mention this in answer why you write extra `$`. Thank you.